# FragmentActivity onSaveInstanceState not getting called

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have seen a few similar questions about `onSaveInstanceState` not getting called for `Fragment`s, but in my case `Fragment`s work fine, it's the main `FragmentActivity` that's having trouble.

The relevant code looks fairly simple:

```
public class MyFActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener { 
    String[] allValues; // data to save

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
        Log.d("putting it!", allValues.toString());
        outState.putStringArray("allValues", allValues);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            allValues = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("allValues");
            Log.d("getting it!", allValues.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

When pausing the activity (using the back button), the `onSaveInstanceState` is never called, and consequently, `savedInstanceState` is always `null` within the `onCreate` method upon resuming the app. I tried adding a block like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());      
}
```

which was suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195202/362657 but while `onSaveInstanceState` then gets called, `savedInstanceState` remains `null` within `onCreate` method. What am I missing?

Comment: "When pausing the activity (using the back button)" usually this destroys the Fragment so `savedInstanceState` is lost.  Do you see the appropriate `saveInstanceState` in `onCreate()` when you rotate the device?

Comment: Rather than onCreate, perhaps you should be using onResume()?  If the activity is only paused, then onCreate() should not get called again, onResume() should

Comment: Hm, that explains it! Destroyed it is.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The issue here is that you are misunderstanding how `onSaveInstanceState` works. It is designed to save the state of the `Activity`/`Fragment` in the case that the OS needs to destroy it for memory reasons or configuration changes. This state is then passed back in `onCreate` when the `Activity`/`Fragment` is returned to / restarted.

In a `Fragment`, all of their lifecycle callbacks are directly tied to their parent `Activity`. So `onSaveInstanceState` gets called on the `Fragment` when its parent `Activity` has `onSaveInstanceState` called.

> When pausing the activity (using the back button), the onSaveInstanceState is never called, and consequently, savedInstanceState is always null within the onCreate method upon resuming the app.

When pressing back, the user is destroying the `Activity`, and therefore its children `Fragment`s, so there is no reason to call `onSaveInstanceState`, since the instance is being destroyed. When you reopen the `Activity`, it's a brand new instance, with no saved state, so the `Bundle` passed in `onCreate` is `null`. This is behaving exactly as designed. However, try rotating the device or hitting the home button, then you will see the `Activity` and its children `Fragment`s have `onSaveInstanceState` called, and passed back in `onCreate` when returned to.

The **hack** you added, directly calling `onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());` inside of `onPause`, is a very bad practice, as you should **never** call the lifecycle callbacks directly. Doing so can put your app into illegal states.

If what you really want is for your data to persist beyond an instance of your app, I suggest you look into using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for more advanced data. You can then save your persistent data in `onPause()` or whenever it changes.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I was under the mistaken impression that the back button puts the activity in the background, not destroying it.

Comment: You are very welcome, it's a tricky concept, and isn't documented as well as I would like to see.

Comment: @dymmeh that's awesome, +1 to you sir

Comment: Great explanation. I wasn't sure why onSaveInstanceState wasn't getting called in my fragment. Now I know. Thanks

Comment: `In a Fragment, all of their lifecycle callbacks are directly tied to their parent Activity. So onSaveInstanceState gets called on the Fragment when its parent Activity has onSaveInstanceState called.`
So what about fragments which are hosted by one single activity? Theoretically their such methods like `onSavedInstanceState` and ... will never get called as they are transited in the same activity, right?

Comment: @inverted_index if you are just *replacing* `Fragments` in a single `Activity`, `onSavedInstanceState` will not be called because the `Fragment` being replaced is being tossed out and doesn't need to save any state. However, I *believe* (you may have to test this) if you use a `Fragment` backstack, the OS will call `onSavedInstanceState` on the stacked `Fragments` when/if it needs to. And yes, if the parent `Activity` needs to call `onSavedInstanceState` it will also call it on its children `Fragments` first.

Answer (score 10):

In an update to the accepted answer:

A fragment's `onSaveInstanceState` may be called if you are using a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (rather than `FragmentPagerAdapter`)

**FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view.  When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment.  This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.

And don't forget:

> When using FragmentPagerAdapter the host ViewPager must have a valid ID set.

Answer (score 0):

Not an accurate answer to the question, but may help someone's day.
In my case, I called

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

I replaced the above code as below and things worked

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```