# How to save data in Fragment after start another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragments A,B,C
In fragment A - a get some variable id, from server then i create bundle , put id in it and start fragment B, in this fragment i get id from bundle and display all information by this id on display, but when i start fragment C and then i press button back and return ti fragment B, variable id is null. How can i solve it? I think i can save id in Database,but maybe there is easier way?
i understand that when i press back in fragment C, fragment B want to get information from bundle, thats why i make next:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if (fakeID == null) {
    fakeID = bundle.getString("fakeID");
}
```

Edited:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        fakeID = bundle.getString("fakeID");
    }
    else{
        fakeID = savedInstanceState.getString("fakeID");
    }
 }
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("fakeID", fakeID);
}
```

But when i return to this fragment 
savedInstanceState == null in this statement

```
if (savedInstanceState == null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935322/fragmentactivity-onsaveinstancestate-not-getting-called) `onSaveInstanceState` won't be called unless the activity itself has called it. which means if you are in the same activity changing fragments. `onSavedInstanceChanged` won't be called. Therefore it is null. As the link suggested you have to use either `SharedPreferences` or `Database`.

Comment: Maybe  if (savedInstanceState == null)
        ID=bundle.getInt("ID) instead ID = 0;?

Comment: Ya sure! that is a better suggestion for null condition

Comment: i will try  it now and i will say result to you

Comment: Are you sure that the ID got its value from the bundle not from the savedInstance?! try to add `Log.d("","");` to check from where the value are coming from

Comment: Yes, i have used SharedPreferences and all works fine.

Comment: Delete plesase you idea about SavedInstance and i will check your answer