# How to save and restore recyclerview's position between 2 fragments in the same activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have implemented some fragments which are hosted by a single Activity (they're in the same activity). In one of these fragments (Let's say fragment A), I have a vertical recyclerview.

The problem is arises when I want to navigate from Fragment A to other fragments (Again, in the same activity). Suppose that I'm clicking the middle member of the list, then I navigate to the next fragment. When I want to back into the first fragment (Fragment A), it inflates the list from first. Seeming that it looses its position, however, using `onSaveInstanceState()` and also `onCreateView()`, I try to store and restore the selected item's position every time I quit or enter the fragment.

I think this issue may be originated from fragments' lifecycle which all are in one single activity. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935826/5112804), mentioning :

> In a Fragment, all of their lifecycle callbacks are directly tied to their parent Activity. So onSaveInstanceState gets called on the Fragment when its parent Activity has onSaveInstanceState called.

and that's why I emphasize on the "single" activity. How can we handle such situation?

I have debugged my program and `onSaveInstanceState` and `onCreateView` were not even called when they were supposed to. Below is my attempted code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        selectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_KEY_SELECTED_ITEM);
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {                    
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        selectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_KEY_SELECTED_ITEM);
    }
    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_mine);

    // mData is a an ArrayList
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mData, getContext(), this.selectedItem);  
    myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);

    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(BUNDLE_KEY_SELECTED_ITEM,selectedItem);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: How are you adding fragments to your Carrier activity? Can you share that code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use [.add()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(android.app.Fragment,java.lang.String)) to add fragments to your activity than [.replace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,android.app.Fragment)), Which preserves the state of the fragment within the activity, and if using replace function which will cause the `onCreateView` callback to trigger again.